Inconsistent Time Display in Grafana Bar Chart with PostgreSQL Data Source
I'm experiencing a strange issue with my Grafana bar chart when using a PostgreSQL data source. Occasionally, the time on the x-axis displays as "00:00:00" instead of the correct time. However, when I hover over the bars, the detailed time shows up correctly. This issue sometimes resolves itself but then reappears unpredictably.
Grafana Bar Chart
Inspect Data Format: Verified the format of the time data returned by the query.
